# Flutter Navigation Issue back button unexpected behavior

Tags: android, flutter, dart, navigation

I have some routes pushed by `Navigator.of(context).push` and expect that flutter will `pop()` it on user back button pressed, but it closes the App.

Here I created a syntetic example with such route:

**Test1Page** -> **Test2Page** -> **Test3Page** -> **Press Back Button**

- **expected:** go back to **Test2Page**
- **actual:** close App

Code:

**Test1Page**

```dart
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:simple_chat_grpc_flutter/src/pages/test2_page.dart';
    
    class Test1Page extends StatelessWidget {
      const Test1Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return TextButton(
            onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (context) => const Test2Page(),
                )),
            child: const Text('goto 2'));
      }
    }
```

**Test2Page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:simple_chat_grpc_flutter/src/pages/test3_page.dart';

class Test2Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test2Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const Test3Page(),
            )),
        child: const Text('goto 3'));
  }
}
```

**Text3Page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'test1_page.dart';

class Test3Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test3Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => const Test1Page(),
            )),
        child: const Text('goto 1'));
  }
}
```

**MyApp**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:simple_chat_grpc_flutter/src/pages/test1_page.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      restorationScopeId: 'app',
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
      ],
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle,

      home: const Test1Page(),
    );
  }
}
```

**main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hydrated_bloc/hydrated_bloc.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

import 'src/app.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // Disable the 'debug' banner
  WidgetsApp.debugAllowBannerOverride = false;

  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
    storageDirectory: kIsWeb
        ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
        : await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

Flutter Doctor:

```
    [√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.3.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19045.2251], locale en-US)
    [√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
    [√] Chrome - develop for the web
    [√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 16.11.5)
    [!] Android Studio (version 2022.1)
        X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    [!] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
        X Unable to find bundled Java version.
    [√] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2022.2)
    [√] VS Code (version 1.73.1)
    [√] Connected device (4 available)
    [√] HTTP Host Availability
```

**Update:**
I loose 1 day struggling with it and I think that there is no simple solutions, and something wrong with Project, because it always worked in such way but now not.

**My Super Solution:**
I recreate a new Project and copy all code to a new one, and now it's working.

**P.S.**
`flutter create --platforms android .` didn't work

**P.P.S.**
Will be happy for some comments, because I don't think that it's solved case and it's interesting why it's happen

Answer (score 0):

I added **routes** to your MyApp and **Navigator.pushReplacementNamed** to process the onPressed action

**MyApp**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_gen/gen_l10n/app_localizations.dart';
import 'package:flutter_localizations/flutter_localizations.dart';
import 'package:simple_chat_grpc_flutter/src/pages/test1_page.dart';

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      restorationScopeId: 'app',
      localizationsDelegates: const [
        AppLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalMaterialLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalWidgetsLocalizations.delegate,
        GlobalCupertinoLocalizations.delegate,
      ],
      supportedLocales: const [
        Locale('en', ''), // English, no country code
      ],
      onGenerateTitle: (BuildContext context) => AppLocalizations.of(context)!.appTitle, 

     home: const Test1Page(),
     routes:{ 
            'Test1Page': (_)=>  const Test1Page(),               
            'Test2Page': (_)=>  const Test2Page(),
            'Test3Page': (_)=>  const Test3Page(),

           }
    );
  }
}
```

**Text3Page**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'test1_page.dart';

class Test3Page extends StatelessWidget {
  const Test3Page({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return TextButton(
        onPressed: () =>  Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context,'Test2Page'),
            )),
        child: const Text('goto 2'));
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it doesn't works for me.

Also I don't understand why you do `pushReplacementNamed`, I change it to `pushNamed`, but also tried with `pushReplacementNamed`, just in case if here is some magic.

But anyway, the result doesn't change, it always closes the App on Back Button.